# Making a synchronous Node.JS for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous, synchronization

I've got the following for loop. It works fine, besides the fact that it doesn't wait for the database query to finish before moving on. I understand that node is asynchronous. That's the issue. I need the easiest method to make the for loop run synchronously all the way through before looping.

```
var users = guild.members.map(member => member.id)
  console.log(users.length)
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    console.log(i)
    connection.query("SELECT serverID, userID FROM serverusers WHERE serverID = ? && userID = ?", [guild.id, users[i]], function (err, result) {
      console.log(i + ":" + result)
      if (err) {
        console.log(colors.red(err.stack))
      }
      if (!result) {
        connection.query("INSERT INTO serverusers (serverID, userID) VALUES (?, ?)", [guild.id, users[i]])
      }
    })
  }
```

My end goal is to go through that map of `users` and check if each user is already in the database. If the user isn't, then add the user

Note: I'm using a MySQL database.

Note 2: The main solution I'm finding online is using the [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) library. I looked through its documentation and I couldn't find out which part of the library is used with for loops. Maybe an answer to this might help fix my issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Idk what database module you're using, but if you can promisify the `query` function, you can use async/await. That'll give you async code that runs synchronously.

Comment: To know what to best suggest, we need to understand what kind of result you are trying to accumulate from the loop.  Please show that.

Comment: @EricGuan I'm using MySQL

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm trying to check if users[i] is already in the db and if it isn't, add it to the db

Comment: "*node is asynchronous*" - Technically, it's because JavaScript is fundamentally event based. A common practice is to *not* make it blocking because there is only one thread, but instead you should use Promises.

Comment: So, then why do you have to do them sequentially?  That will slower than running them in parallel.  You do have to keep track of your loop variable differently so you can use it in an async callback, but your code can run in parallel.

Comment: @jfriend00 do you mean have it check for all users and insert into db if they arent there at the same time? that wouldnt work because some users might not need to be added and some might - unless I didnt understand that right

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! It's not a **proper** solution but it solves my problem nonetheless. I simply condensed my for loop into one line. Here's my new code:

```
var users = guild.members.map(member => member.id)
  console.log(users.length)
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    connection.query("INSERT IGNORE serverusers (serverID, userID) VALUES (?, ?)", [guild.id, users[i]])
  }
```

Thanks to anyone to contributed to this post :)

Comment: You could do this in a single query if you build an array of values to insert and then pass it to the connection.query `[[guild.id, firstuser]], [guild.id, seconduser], ...]`  so instead of multiple queries you just do one. It would be much faster i think.

Comment: Just to be clear, this still doesn't do what you think. If you have some statements after the for loop then they will likely run before your db queries finish. That might be ok but i don't think it's what you were asking for.

Comment: @Molda although in this case, it's just 2 users, in some cases it could be in the hundreds or thousands. would it still be more efficient then?

Comment: @ktilcu you're right but in my case, that isn't an issue but definitely something to consider.

Answer (score 0):

I see your answer but i thought I would provide an alternative because I don't think your answer does what you expect.

1. If your async functions fail (`connection.query`) then you will
   never know.
2. Anything after the `for` loop will likely run before those users are
   inserted.

Anyways, here's my answer using promises.

```js
function query (statement, params) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    connection.query(statement, params, function (err, result) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve(result);
    })
  })
}

var users = guild.members.map(member => member.id);
var queries = users
  .map(u => query("INSERT IGNORE serverusers (serverID, userID) VALUES (?, ?)", [guild.id, u]);

Promise.all(queries)
  .then(results => console.log('now it\'s done', result));
  .catch(err => console.log('whoopsies', err));
```

Answer (score 0):

With the async library you can use the following methods:

[async.each](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each):

```
async.each(users, asyncFunctionToDealWithEachUser, callbackForWhenAllUsersHaveBeenProcesssed)
```

or

[async.times](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#times)

```
async.times(users.length, functionToRunForEachUser, callbackForWhenAllUsersHaveBeenProcessed);
```